# How to find out customers going to store A only or store B only or both stores

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Order table

| customer_id | transaction | store |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | Alpha |
| 1 | B | Beta |
| 2 | C | Alpha |
| 3 | D | Beta |
| 3 | D | Beta |
| 4 | E | Beta |

I want to extract data with new column store_visit as below and find the count of customer going to store Alpha, Beta and both stores

| customer_id | store_visit |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Both |
| 2 | Alpha |
| 3 | Beta |
| 4 | Beta |

In this case, the count will be

| store_visit | count |
| --- | --- |
| Both | 1 |
| Alpha | 1 |
| Beta | 2 |

Comment: Please provide DDL + DML commands

Comment: So you have the table at the top and you want two resulting tables, the bottom two, correct?

Comment: The 2nd last table is enough as result

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @order_table table (customer_id int, [transaction] nvarchar(5), store nvarchar(50))

insert into @order_table
values(1,'A','Alpha')
, (1,'B','Beta')
, (2,'C','Alpha')
, (3,'D','Beta')
, (3,'D','Beta')
, (4,'E','Beta')


declare @store_visit_table table (customer_id int, store_visit nvarchar(50))

insert into @store_visit_table
SELECT customer_id
    , CASE WHEN SUM(CASE 
            WHEN store = 'Alpha'
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END) > 0
    AND SUM(CASE 
            WHEN store = 'Beta'
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END) > 0 then 'Both' WHEN SUM(CASE 
            WHEN store = 'Alpha'
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END) > 0 then 'Alpha' WHEN SUM(CASE 
            WHEN store = 'Beta'
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END) > 0 then 'Beta' ELSE 'Nowhere' end as store_visit
FROM @order_table
GROUP BY customer_id
    , rollup(store)
    having GROUPING_ID(store) = 1

select * from @store_visit_table

select store_visit, count(store_visit) as count from @store_visit_table GROUP BY store_visit
```

Comment: Sorry I'm new to SQL here. Based on the above, if customer visits Alpha store 3 times, wouldn't it will make the summation calculation for store_visit to 3?

Comment: Yes, the result of this SUM(CASE WHEN store = 'Alpha' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) would be 3. The first query checks if this is > 0, since this is true the query knows the customer went to Alpha. If this is also true for Beta, then the first condition in the query is also true. The output will be both, if the customer didn't go to Beta, the second condition will be true and the output will be Alpha.